# C#, Sharepoint - GetDescription() & SetDescription() of the Taxonomy Term

Tags: taxonomy, term-set, taxonomyfieldvalue

I want to be able to manage the GetDescription() and SetDescription() of the Taxonomy Term(as a managed metadata). 
In order to get the value of the Description, not of the Label of the Taxonomy Term.

[image]
 How should I manage these functions?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("URL of site"))
        {
            TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
            TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["MMMD Service"];
            Group group = termStore.Groups["Term Group"];               
            TermSet termSet = group.TermSets["Term Set"];
            Term term = termSet.Terms["term"];
            term.SetDescription("Test", 1033);           
            termStore.CommitAll();            
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the case! Even though I was more interested in the GetDescription().     The syntax would be term.GetDescription();